# How can I make the document library have columns that show checked out details in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: check-out

How can I make the document library have columns that show if the it’s checked out, who checked it out, and when it was checked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the document library to require check out, you get the Checked Out To column for free. This also implies that if the field is empty it is not checked out. The only thing you don't have is an indicator of when it was checked out.

Comment: Thanks, Let me check if we could still use the modified column value as indicator of when it was checked out.